# What role does gender play in the Realms of Despair?

Tags: realms-of-despair

I can make my character male, female or neutral gender.

Is there any game play consideration that would influence my decision or is it purely a personal preference?

Comment: I don't know, but I have to say that's pretty cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a new player the decision of which gender to play is purely a personal, perhaps social  one.  While [some equipment](http://www.silverwolf-den.com/cgi-bin/db.cgi?db=equip2&uid=default&Itemname=&InGame=---&CSize=---&Level-gt=&Level-lt=&Area=---&Wear=---&Type=---&Specials=&Magic=---&Good=---&Neutral=---&Evil=---&Male=n&Female=y&Neuter=n&PKill=---&Wgt=&AC=&AffAC=&Dam=&HR=&DR=&Hp=&Mana=&Moves=&Str=&Int=&Wis=&Dex=&Con=&Cha=&Lck=&SvParalysis=&SvRod=&SvPoison=&SvBreath=&SvSpell=&AFFby=&Spells=&Charges=&keyword=&mh=100&sb=---&so=ascend&view_records=View%20Records), deities and fights are gender sensitive almost 
universally these can be circumvented by application of the change sex spell.

As regards the gender sensitive equipment (primarily female only) none of it is so powerful to be game changing though some, like the "[Satan plate](http://rodpedia.poromenos.org/wiki/Corselette_of_the_Furies)" are nice improvements over stock items.

For deity choices, both [Estathius](http://rodpedia.poromenos.org/wiki/Estathius) and [Sarane](http://rodpedia.poromenos.org/wiki/Sarane) are sensitive to gender.  Neither of these deities will actively penalize you if you use a change sex spell to devote to them, though you will need to use the spell again later on to gain their favor (outside the scope of this question).

There is one known fight in which a female character is required to have a particular item appear, however, this is also easily circumvented with the change sex spell.

Some experienced players will create a character of a particular gender in order to not need to use the change sex spell, but this is more of an optimization than a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

It can affect whether you can devote to the deity Sarane which only accepts females.

It can affect what equipment you can wear as some equipment is gender specific such as: [Chastity Belt](http://rodpedia.poromenos.org/wiki/A_gilded_chastity_belt), [High-heel Boots](http://rodpedia.poromenos.org/wiki/A_pair_of_black,_high_heel_boots), [Maid Costume](http://rodpedia.poromenos.org/wiki/A_tight-fitting_maid_costume), [Silken Robes](http://rodpedia.poromenos.org/wiki/The_silken,_grey_robes_of_magnificence), [White Smock](http://rodpedia.poromenos.org/wiki/The_white_smock_of_amelioration), [Ravenell Crested Ring Mail](http://rodpedia.poromenos.org/wiki/A_suit_of_Ravenell_crested_ringmail), [Unholy Robes](http://rodpedia.poromenos.org/wiki/The_Unholy_Robes_of_the_Invoker), [Six-Fingered Glove](http://rodpedia.poromenos.org/wiki/A_six_fingered_glove), and probably more...

Comment: Do you have a character on Realms skovacs?

Comment: Actually no. I am interested, but all of my answers for this game are based on research of public information. I could have guessed based on the nature of the questions that you might be an active player, but couldn't be sure. Either way, I figured answering was worth a shot because either you were new to the game and needed answers or you were just going to post your own answers anyway and my answers if at least semi-competent wouldn't really hurt anything.

Comment: Your answers are good, I was just curious :)  I'm trying to get more people from there to use this as a resource, starting with some how do I get started questions.